# Why am I getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5

Tags: java, csv, boolean, pipe

can someone help me to solve this issue? Not so sure why I am getting **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5**

here is the document index I have where the flag is located

Data.csv

```
docID, docName, docAddress, docPayment, docDate, docFlag
"12|"User"|"park"|"0.0"|"20230217"|""
```

```
private DocumentExtract builExtract(String[] documents){
    if(documents== null || documents.length <= 0){
        return null;
}

DocumentExtract documentExtract= new DocumentExtract();     
String flag = documents[5].trim();

if(!flag.isEmpty()){
    if(flag.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            documentExtract.setFlag(false);
    }else{
        documentExtract.setFlag(true);
            }
}else{
    documentExtract.setFlag(false);
}
        
return documentExtract;
```

DocumentExtract() class

```
private Boolean flag;

public Boolean getFlag() {
        return flag;
    }
public void setFlag(Boolean flag) {
        this.flag= flag;
    }
```

Hope to learn from people here too, your reply will be highly appreciate

Comment: What is `documents`?

Comment: @kiner_shah documents is where the value is stored, I posted above for reference

Comment: Is it an array of strings?

Comment: @kiner_shah I don't think so it is a Array of String, I am just new to java, my apology

Comment: Is this the whole code needed for reproducing the issue?

Comment: @kiner_shah yes, Iam getting an error at the line String flag = documents[5].trim();

Comment: Erm ... no it isn't!  I can't see where you are creating and initializing (reading) `documents` and that will be where the actual problem is.  The exception is simply saying that `documents` doesn't have a `documents[5]` which means that `documents.length` is smaller than 6.

Comment: Yes `String[]` **does** mean array of `String`.

Comment: @StephenC should I replace the value documents[5] to [6]? I thought that document always starts at 0 that's why I set it to 5 since the length is 6

Comment: No.  Think about it.  If 5 is too large, then 6 is also too large!!  What you really need to do is look at the code that is creating / initializing / reading the value that ends up as `documents`.  Hint: read the javadocs for the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception.  Find out what it *means*.   Clearly the length is NOT 6.

Comment: "12|"User"|"park"|"0.0"|"20230217"|"" : it seems that a double quote is missing ( after 12, before | )

Comment: I would suggest to first print documents array, and see the elements that you have in that array, that would give an idea if everything is working as expected.

Comment: @Notron I get the expected value after I insert data on index[5], and it seems right. But when empty string on index[5], it gives an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Euphoria then it seems that when you have empy string you are not adding that to the list, can you show how you are adding elements to documents array ? (since I can't see that in the above code)

Comment: Thanks All! Problem solved by getting the length of documents and use null condition for the if(documents.length > 5){ 
if(documents[5] != null){
 if(!flag.isEmpty()){
    if(flag.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            documentExtract.setFlag(false);
    }else{
        documentExtract.setFlag(true);
            }
}else{
    documentExtract.setFlag(false);
}
        
return documentExtract;